# cat command fails in bash script : cat: /dev/rfcomm0: No such device or address

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cat

I want to listen bluetooth connection and print received text messages. I can do this with following commands:`sudo rfcomm listen hci0 &` and then i connect with another device to bluetooth. When connection is established, rfcomm command prints

> Connection from DeviceMAC to /dev/rfcomm

Then i execute `cat /dev/rfcomm0` command to listen and print received messages. I want to automate this with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< <(sudo rfcomm listen hci0 &)
echo "executed"
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
   *Connection*)
      echo "Connection established."
      cat "/dev/rfcomm0"
      break
      ;;
   *)
      echo "'$line' does not Connection."
      ;;
   esac
done <&3

exec 3<&-
```

This bash script fails in cat command and i get the following error:

> cat: /dev/rfcomm0: No such device or address

Why cat command fails in bash script?

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue. What happens if you put `sleep 1` before `cat /dev/rfcomm0`?

Comment: I tried sleep 5 but not worked.

Comment: Before doing the `cat`, verify with `ls /dev/*` what you have in `/dev`. Maybe it's a spelling problem.

Comment: I double checked for spelling problem but i will try it. It seems that there is something like access right problem or /dev/rfcomm0 uses another file descriptor name inside bash script.